# switch masterpage button default button property in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, defaultbutton

I'm developing an ASP.NET web app (C#, VS2010), I have a master page which has a button (search button) and a textbox, when I press enter, this search button executes, but I don't want this master page search button to work when I'm in my login page. In my login page I have two textboxes and another button (login button), I want this login button to work as default button (execute with enter key) when I'm in login page. Of course I've not used any javascript or DefaultButton property at all

how can I disable masterpage button enter key in my login page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a [`DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) around each area you want default buttons, it will then use the part of the form that has focus:

```
<asp:Panel id="SearchPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="Search" >
      <asp:Button id="Search" runat="server" Text="Search" />
<asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="LoginPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="Login" >
      <asp:Button id="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" />
<asp:Panel>
```

Comment: thanks, but can I disable my masterpage button with thick trick?

Comment: Sure you can...., just letting you know that ASP.NET handles it normally via the DefultButton.

Comment: I put my search button (in masterpage) inside a panel which has its DefaultButton property to an invisible button, but it is still performing its behavior

Answer (score 1):

In your login Page get a reference to Master Page button control  and then disable it.

```
 Button b = Master.FindControl("ButtonID");
 b.Enable= false;
```

To change default buton of master page change it's default button in master page codebehind

```
form1.DefaultButton = "New button ID";

oR  from login page codebehind

Form.DefaultButton = "New button ID";
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to disable my master page button, this is what I want: when my user is in LOGIN page, I want ENTER key to press login button not the masterpage button